# Django Admin: Intersection (Natural Inner Join) between Two Models

Tags: sql, django, join, orm, admin

I'm a Django beginner. I have two models that I would like to display as one table in the Django admin interface. Below are the simplified versions of the models:

```
class Final_Application_Personal_Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    id_no = models.CharField(max_length=14)

class Final_Application_Beneficiary_Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    beneficiary_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    beneficiary_id_no = models.CharField(max_length=14)
```

I suppose because these two models conceptually form part of one form (a Final_Application form), I could have maybe used Django's formwizard - however, because in reality both personal details and beneficiary details are quite a lot to fill in, I thought I'd want to give the user a chance to fill them in separately (in django formwizard, as far as I know, if the user doesn't fill out all the data at once, then all previous data is also lost because the form can't be saved with unvalidated fields).

I want to join the two models in Django admin so that the administrative user can see all a user's information (personal details and beneficiary's details) on one page. So, I'd like to do an inner join on the above-mentioned tables on the field 'user'. The SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Final_Application_Personal_Detail
  JOIN Final_Application_Beneficiary_Detail
  ON Final_Application_Personal_Detail.user = Final_Application_Beneficiary_Detail.user
```

With regards to Django's ORM, I've looked into the keyword argument related_to in order to join the tables. I don't think that will work, however...it seems as if 'select_related' is just another way to stipulate a foreign key. I now want to use raw SQL in order to join the tables. I've tried using the cursor function to implement raw SQL, but I don't quite know how to implement it so that the output shows in Django's admin interface. Also, I'm a little bit afraid of using raw SQL, because as far as I understand, raw SQL can introduce security risks (I've read that Django's ORM prevents SQL injections).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with django admin. However, you can use [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to edit both models in the User admin.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class Final_Application_Personal_DetailInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Final_Final_Applicationl_Detail

class Final_Application_Beneficiary_DetailInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Final_Final_Application_Beneficiary_Detail

admin.site.unregister(User)

@admin.register(User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [
        Final_Application_Personal_DetailInline,
        Final_Application_Beneficiary_DetailInline,
    ]
```